# Build Error with ndk jni for curl

Tags: android, curl, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am stuck at compilation of curl with the error:

```
$ndk-build
Android NDK: Building for application 'curl' 
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'curl' in sources/curl//jni/Android.mk. 
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by sources/curl//jni/Android.mk. 
build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting. . Stop.
```

Can anyone provide the procedure you used to compile the dependencies?

Comment: Could you post your Android.mk (the section for the module curl)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when trying to include a precompiled static library into a NDK project. I fixed it by editing my project's Android.mk file to move the line `$(call import-module,<MY_MODULE_NAME>)` to the very end of the file (after `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`).

Comment: Thanks for help but I couldn't find $(call import-module,<MY_MODULE_NAME> in my android.mk

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was adding a shared library that needed gnustl_shared, so I added it to my Android.mk file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libgnustl_shared
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_STATIC_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../native_libs/$(TARGET_ARCH)/libgnustl_shared.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The conflict I got was this:

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'gnustl_shared' in jni/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by c:/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk.
```

The reason was because **I was already using it as a static library**. This was in Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

The solution was to change it to `APP_STL := gnustl_shared`, and then to remove the `LOCAL_MODULE := libgnustl_shared` section from Android.mk.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem because I used wrong command.

in Android.mk dir, I used "`ndk-build -f Android.mk`",this was causing the problem
    `Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'SRC' in Android.mk.`
    `Android NDK: But this module was already defined by ...`

but when I input "`ndk-build`",build succeeded!